# Select 1 record out of many for time period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to select records where i only have 1 record if there are overlapping dates. I have looked around and found questions close but could not get them to work for what problem i have. If you could help me out i would greatly appreciate it.

Problem is a member can have many visits with effective and end dates. Cannot have overlapping time to be enrolled. How would i only have 1 record if there is an overlapping time with the same effective date?

I have tried max EndDate etc.. but doesnt work. Also i can have more than 2 records for 1 member with same TIN and dates. Hence the need to get MIN/MAX dates as one record for that time period.
Data:

```
MEMBER - TIN - EffectiveDate - EndDate
12345   4567   2016-11-18      2016-11-19 --dont want this record
12345   4567   2016-11-18      2017-11-20 --good
12345   5678   2016-11-18      2016-12-30 --good, different TIN

    Select t1.MEMBER, t1.TIN, t1.EFF_DT
    , Case When (select t2.MEMBER = t1.MEMBER and t1.Eff_DT = t2.END_DT 
                 THEN t2.END_DT ELSE t1.END_DT
                 END AS END_DT
                )t2
    FROM Table_A t1
    WHERE t1.MEMBER = t2.MEMBER
    order by t1.MEMBER
```

hope i got code right from what i tried.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work?

Comment: I cannot get rid of the record i do not want. comes back with all the records.

Comment: Show us your query.

Comment: added query to question

Answer (score 2):

i guess this is what you want ?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MEMBER, TIN, EFFECTIVE_DATE 
                                          ORDER BY END_DATE DESC)
    FROM   yourtable
) d
where d.RN = 1
```

if not, please do show us your expected result

Comment: This worked. i tried this type of query earlier today but i did not use the DESC and i think i had to many fields in the Partition BY area. Used what you had a viola it got rid of the extra rows. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Very common query challenge.  Check out this article:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

You could try:

```
select t1.*
from (
   select MEMBER, TIN, MIN(EffectiveDate) AS MinDate, MAX(EndDate) AS MaxDate
   from table_name group by MEMBER, TIN
) as t1 inner join table_name as t2
    on t1.MEMBER = t2.MEMBER and t1.TIN = t2.TIN;
```

Comment: That did not work. Got back more records then original amount.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use the solutions above. Can you provide the query that you've tried to run? You should be able to do the following:

```
SELECT Member, TIN, MAX(EndDate) as endDate
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY Member, TIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT t.member, t.tin, t.effectivedate, t.enddate 
FROM TABLE_A t 
GROUP BY t.tin, t.member, t.enddate 
HAVING t.enddate = 
                  (
                  SELECT MAX(tt.enddate)
                  FROM TABLE_A tt
                  WHERE t.member = tt.member
                  AND t.tin = tt.tin
                  )
```

Comment: This was close. still kept an extra record with a date overlapping. had 2 records with eff_dt 2016-11-18 and 2016-11-20. So i need only the 2016-11-18, min record keep. Thanks for the help. i will be able to use what you have in the future i am sure.